# Is there any advantage to async/await on another thread?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I have a WPF client that uses an external library that offers async API support but ***also performs some CPU bound work*** when using said async methods (such as entity materialization, parsing, etc). Is there any benefit to using the async methods being that I want the CPU bound work on another thread anyway?  Not using `Task.Run()` to call those methods causes some animation jitter because the CPU bound work is still occurring on the dispatcher in the message loop but if an API offers async support I prefer to use that instead of sync code.

I presume *there is* benefit in using the async API *if* it enables the reuse of my thread pool thread offered by the `Task.Run()`.  I think this is one of the primary benefits of async/await in ASP.NET so I'm presuming reuse of the thread pool thread is also a benefit on the client.

**UPDATE**

Updated question to state *CPU* bound work as pointed out by Stephen.  I can see another advantage to utilizing the async API of the external library by my services even though I wrap it in Task.Run() in my ViewModel. That is that any other caller to my services will get async for free without having to change the implementation at that time or make a separate service.

Comment: To the downvoters, is it because I didn't add code or because you just think the question is inappropriate?  I don't understand downvoting an honest question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean CPU-bound, not I/O-bound.

`Task.Run` uses thread pool threads, which can be reused. This doesn't have anything to do with `async` or ASP.NET.

In your use case, you're interested in keeping the UI responsive, but there's an API with mixed I/O and CPU methods. In this case, it's perfectly appropriate to use `Task.Run` to call those API methods.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question.  I couldn't see where anyone else had asked this particular question so I really appreciate your input.